# User unable to configure taskboard settings on sprint in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, permissions

I have a user who is both Project Admin and Team Admin (all teams) within a project in Azure DevOps. They appear to be unrestricted within the project except when they attempt to modify sprint taskboard settings. They are immediately presented with a warning:

> 'You do not have sufficient permissions to configure cards for this
> team. You must either be a team administrator or a project
> administrator.'

As the user is both project/team admin and able to modify the project's process, I'm at a loss as to what is missing. Or could this possibly be a bug? This is the only thing within the project that is blocking the user.

The screen is under 'Boards/Sprints/[Sprint Name]/[Cog icon in top right]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access level of this user is stakeholder. Please contact members of the Project Collection Administrators group to [change the access level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#manage-users) of the user to Basic.

Users with Stakeholder access level have partial access to Azure Boards in private projects. You can find more detailed information about [access level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops) in this document.